# Silverlight GridSplitter: simulate "snap to grid"

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, gridsplitter

I am working with Silverlight 3.

I have a grid with 2 columns and with a GridSplitter between them.
How do I make the GridSplitter snap to 5px increment when dragged?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is you'll have to capture the MouseLeftButtonDown event and detect dragging. If not dragging, then cancel the event.  If dragging is detected, capture the start position in a class variable. In MouseMove, compare the mouse position to the start position and determine whether to increment or decrement the Grid Splitter position.

To get this to work, I think you will need to adjust the width of the left grid column programmatically based on the increment/decrement decision above.

I'll be curious to see how this goes.

Comment: Thanks, Joel. What you are saying is fair and I might have to go that way. For now, though, I am waiting for some other answers before marking any as "accepted".

Comment: This is a pertinent answer so I am marking it as accepted. I kind of expected to have other suggestions too.

Answer (score 0):

The GridSplitter exposes the DragIncrement property that sets the minimum distance that a user must drag a mouse to resize rows or columns.  Therefore, you could do something like:

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DragIncrement="5"/>
```

Edit: I just realized that you were talking about Silverlight.  Looks like the DragIncrement property is only available in WPF.  Sorry about your luck.

Comment: yes, the DragIncrement property is what I want, but unfortunately in Silverlight 3 we only have a private constant with a value of 1.